# How to use the mvn -D to set (multiple) properties in Maven via command line?

Tags: java, maven, command-line, properties

How to use the `mvn -D` in maven? How to set a property (or multiple properties) using it?

Are there any official articles for `mvn -D`?

I couldn't find one. Thanks.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The proper way to set a property via command-line using `-D` is:

```
mvn -DpropertyName=propertyValue clean package
```

- If `propertyName` doesn't exist in the `pom.xml`, it will be set.
- If `propertyName` already exists in the `pom.xml`, its value will be **overwritten** by the one passed as argument via `-D`.

To send **multiple variables**, use multiple space delimited `-D`s:

```
mvn -DpropA=valueA -DpropB=valueB -DpropC=valueC clean package
```

You can check more details about properties in [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/index.html). More specifically, in section: [**6.1. Maven Command Line Options/6.1.1. Defining Properties**](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-define-prop).

#### Example:

If you have in your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <theme>myDefaultTheme</theme>
</properties>
```

Then `mvn -Dtheme=halloween clean package` would overwrite `theme`s value during this execution, having the **effect** as if you had:

```
<properties>
    <theme>halloween</theme>
</properties>
```

Comment: if I want to set more the one property how to write it? -Dxx=11 -Dyy=2?

Comment: @jiafu yes, just space delimited

Comment: Yes, as #earcam said, multiple space separated `-D`s is the correct way, just like you did: `-Dxx=11 -Dyy=2`. Now if you have several variables that are usually used together, you should consider using profiles. Check the item ["6.1.3. Using Build Profiles"](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) of that reference link I posted in the answer.

Comment: Do I need to place the system properties before the **clean package** command ? I don't understand why `mvn clean package -DskipTests` works, whereas the **skipTests** is placed after the command **clean package**

Comment: @OlivierBoissé It works because it doesn't matter if you put the variables before or after the goals, simples as that.

Comment: @acdcjunior I realize this is an old question but can you set multiple values to the one property? For example, -Dcom.CORSclient=http://localhost:8081 & http://localhost:8082