# Jenkins: Goals and options in Maven plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In **Jenkins config**, we have *Goals and options*, against which we *add the path of .xml* file which we have to execute. Like:

```
clean test -DpathToMySuiteFile_1=sanity.xml
```

In above line, what is the work of `-D`?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332857/how-to-use-the-mvn-d-to-set-multiple-properties-in-maven-via-command-line :)

Answer (score 0):

It is connected with Maven (and Maven plugin), not Jenkins itself.

`-D` option is used to define system properties for Maven via command-line, e.g.:

```
mvn clean test -Dproperty1=propertyValue2 -Dproperty2=propertyValue2
```

So, in your case, `-D` just sets `sanity.xml` value to `DpathToMySuiteFile_1` variable.

This option is usually used to customize the behavior of Maven plugins. See details [here](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-define-prop).

Update: as @snukone already mentioned, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17332863/10721592) is the detailed answer.