# How to capture arguments from command line from maven

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, testng

Currently Im working in a Maven project where I need to run tests in different environments.
The idea is be possible to pass the environment as argument as examples below:

- mvn test -Pdev
- mvn test -Puat

How can I capture this argument -P from command line?

Thanks!

Comment: a space is missing, "mvn test -P dev"

Comment: With `-P` you are activating profiles, do these profiles exist in your `pom.xml`? To whom do you want to pass the argument? To a Maven plugin, a JUnit Test, or what?

Comment: Ive found an solution using arguments in -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332857/how-to-use-the-mvn-d-to-set-multiple-properties-in-maven-via-command-line

Comment: Worked following the steps in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332857/how-to-use-the-mvn-d-to-set-multiple-properties-in-maven-via-command-line